# Eigenvalues of regular graphs

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could someone give me a hint for exercise 2.iii of [these lecture notes](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/245b-notes-1-basic-theory-of-expander-graphs/)? The exercise asks to show that a $k$-regular undirected graph (without loops) whose adjacency matrix $A$ has eigenvalues $k=\lambda_1(A) \geq \lambda_2(A) \geq \cdots \geq \lambda_n(A)$ satisfies $$\max(|\lambda_2(A)|, |\lambda_n(A)|) \geq \sqrt{k} - o(1).$$

Comment: What parameter is the little-o depending on? $k$? $n$?

Comment: It goes to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but $k$ is fixed.

Comment: From previous parts and the discussion before, you know $\lambda_1$, you know both $\sum \lambda_i$ and $\sum \lambda_i^2$, and you know that $\max(\lambda_2^2,\lambda_n^2)\geq \lambda_i$ for $i\neq 1$.  Note that the minimum possible maximum will be achieved when every $|\lambda_i|^2$ ($i\neq 1$) is equal.

Comment: Typo above.  Should be $\max(\lambda_2^2,\lambda_n^2)\geq \lambda_i^2$.

Comment: Ah, yes. Thanks!